# Is there any way to directly handle json in android/java without convert

Tags: android, json

> Sloved with jackson

I have a json like this

```
{
    "id":"tcsId",
    "status":0,
    "value":[
        {
            "teachClassMaster":{
                "maxStudCnt":"130",
                "lessonSchedules":[
                    {
                        "classroom":{
                            "roomId":"649",
                            "fullName":""
                        },
                        "timeBlock":{
                            "classSet":"480",
                            "name":"",
                            "endWeek":"16",
                            "beginWeek":"9",
                            "tmbId":"7905",
                            "dayOfWeek":"2"
                        },
                        "lsschId":"63652"
                    }
                ],
                "studCnt":"128",
                "lessonTeachers":[
                    {
                        "teacher":{
                            "name":"",
                            "teacherId":"7528"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "name":"(2015-2016-1)-ac13544006-601026-1",
                "tcmId":"46336",
                "lessonSegment":{
                    "lssgId":"25512",
                    "lesson":{
                        "courseInfo":{
                            "courName":""
                        }
                    },
                    "fullName":""
                }
            },
            "tcsId":"3626332",
            "student":null,
            "dateAccept":"2015-06-16T20:42:05"
        }
    ]
}
```

The structure is very complex, if I use the normal way(convert to Object), I will have plenty of useless classes, and the code will be rather messy.

Is there any way to directly pick out a certain value, like using a['teachClassMaster']['lessonSchedules'][0]['classRoom']['roomId'] to get 649?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried searching google for: java json xpath

Comment: Going to try it, thanks.